# Grunt with Bower Slow Process when including packages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gruntjs, bower

I have a grunt workflow but I have some problems with the compiling time of sass. I use grunt-contrib-sass to compile my stylesheet but the problem is that I am currently loading assets from my bower imports (packages such as bootstrap-sass that I have included.)

I noticed that when including such a package it take way longer to actually compile the file, 7-10seconds and If I remove the @import bootstrap from my scss file it will only take a second to compile my file if I reload the grunt compile.

@import '../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';

@import (my custom modules)

There must be a smarter way of making this work? Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try `libsass`, a C/C++ port of the library.

http://sass-lang.com/libsass

> Sass was originally written in Ruby. libSass is a C/C++ port of the
>   Sass engine. The point is to be simple, faster, and easy to integrate.